# zip extraction in sharepoint server 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, zip

how to upload and extract zip file in sharepoint server 2010?

Answer (score 0):

A solution might be to use a Document Library to upload the zip documents and then hook up an event handler on it to intercept uploaded documents and unzip them, you can then decide what to do with it, you can even store the unzipped version and drop the original file .

You can see an example here on how to create an event handler for a document library:

http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/walkthroughs/event-receivers-walkthrough2/

Answer (score 0):

The event receiver approach for working with Zip files (or any potentially large documents) has several limitations, like potentially using lots of server memory during the unzip process or having the thread be terminated by IIS if it takes too long to run, which means you won't be able to handle any non-trivial zip files.

There's a package that handles these issues and more here:
http://www.blackbladeinc.com/en-us/products/wsszip/Pages/WhatsNew.aspx

Some of what that software handles that are hard to do with just an event receiver include:

- forms-based / claims-based authentication
- downloading and uploading of very large (multi-gigabyte) Zip files
- SharePoint farms with load-balanced web servers

Comment: Event Handlers are handled by the OWSTimer not IIS what do you mean the thread can be terminated by IIS? Also please elaborate how come that software package will use less memory on the extraction process than an event handler?

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner. Event receivers can run in the W3wp.exe process or in OWSTIMER.exe, depending on the type of event receiver and how it is configured. Take a look at the thread [Which process do event receivers run under?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27717/which-process-do-event-receivers-run-under)

Comment: Thanks the the reply, yes that is correct depending if they are async or not, you probably should amend your reply for completion sake. Also What about your claim that it will use less memory. Can you please elaborate. I don't understand why a third party library would use less memory on the extraction process. Thanks